# teb local planner installation

Tags: ros, teb-local-planner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone

I am kind of new for the ROS, and when I tried to follow the instruction from ROS wiki to install the teb_local_planner, I have encounter some error, I am currently using ubuntu 14.04LTS.

So here is the prompt I used and the reply I receive
*samping@samping-HP-250-G4-Notebook-PC://$ sudo apt-get install ros-{distro}-teb-local-planner
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree

Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ros-{distro}-teb-local-planner*

Can anyone provide me some help on installing this package?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/232994/teb-local-planner-installation/) by [samping](https://answers.ros.org/users/26715/samping/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2016-04-27

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [croesmann](https://answers.ros.org/users/12166/croesmann/) on 2016-05-02**:
hey, please accept the answer if it has solved your issue

**Comment by [samping](https://answers.ros.org/users/26715/samping/) on 2016-05-02**:
How do I accept it, I can't find the button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey,

just replace `{distro}` in the command with your ROS-Distribution (indigo, jade):

On indigo:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-teb-local-planner
```

On jade:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-jade-teb-local-planner
```

---

Originally posted by [croesmann](https://answers.ros.org/users/12166/croesmann/) with karma: 2531 on 2016-04-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [croesmann](https://answers.ros.org/users/12166/croesmann/) on 2016-04-27**:
I've updated the tutorials page to include buttons for version selection and hence avoiding {distro} in commands.

**Comment by [zkytony](https://answers.ros.org/users/26716/zkytony/) on 2016-07-12**:
Hi croesmann, I'm still not able to install teb_local_planner for indigo (on Ubuntu 16.04), even with the command sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-teb-local-planner. Can you check if it works for you now?

**Comment by [zkytony](https://answers.ros.org/users/26716/zkytony/) on 2016-07-12**:
I also searched on Ubuntu's App Directory, but could not find any package relating to "teb"

**Comment by [croesmann](https://answers.ros.org/users/12166/croesmann/) on 2016-07-12**:
hi @kaiyu, if you are on Ubuntu 16.04, you are probably running ROS Kinetic since Indigo is not available for 16.04. After successfully installing ROS, invoke `sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-teb-local-planner`.